# Select count in SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a parameter on my page `$name = $_GET['name']`.
If nothing is passed through the parameter then the page dies (this works fine).

```
if(!isset($name) || $name == ""){
        http_response_code(404);
        include('404');
        die();
}
```

However when I try to check if the parameter value provided exists in my database, it doesn't work. For example, if I enter `adcdefg`, although it does not exist the page still loads when it is supposed to die.

```
$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE name = :name");
    $stmt->execute(array(":name" => $name));
    while ($selectCC = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $count_check = $selectCC['count'];
        if($count_check < 1){
            http_response_code(404);
            die();
        }
    }
```

This code is set under my database connection and session include files so should in theory work fine. Any help?

Comment: if you echo out $count_check after this line $count_check = $selectCC['count']; what do you get

Comment: When I echo it I get 9

Comment: well that's a problem this block will on die if the count is < 1, so what does your table look like and if you don't mind showing some of the data? is there a user named "abcdefg"?  Is there something wrong with your query? what library are you using to access the database?

Comment: also if you can connect directly to the database and run 
`select COUNT(*) as count from users where name ="abcdefg"` and see what you get